# Выбрать из текста ссылки и из них текст

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Есть текст который набирается сам на странице таким образом:

```
var arr = new Array(data.text);
        $.each(arr, function(){         
            $.each(this, function(i,v){             
                $(post_selectors.message_text).delay(15).queue(function (next) {  
                    $(this).append(v);                
                next();
                })   
            })
        })
```

в этом тексте могут быть ссылки, скрипт набирает эти ссылки соответственно html кодом, как сделать так, что бы скрипт набирал только текст с ссылок, или же придумать другое решение?

Comment: а ссылки должны оставаться ссылками ?

    console.log($('<div>').html('<a href="aaa">Hello World</a>').text());

Comment: решено, спасибо